# Number of cyclically symmetric tc-plane partitions vs a determinant

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

The ubiquitous [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) can be given by $C_0:=1$ and $C_{n+1}=\sum_{i+j=n}^nC_iC_j$.
In the same spirit, one may define the sequence $T_0:=1$ and $T_{n+1}=\sum_{i+j+k=n}T_iT_jT_k$ listed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001764).

Keep in mind that $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ while $T_n=\frac1{2n+1}\binom{3n}n$. They have a shared/similar property: $C_n=\frac1{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}n$ and $T_n=\frac1{3n+1}\binom{3n+1}n$ enumerate $(n,n+1)$-core partitions and $(n,2n+1)$-core partitions [here is a quick reference on the topic](https://sumry.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/CountingOversemigroupsPoster.pdf).

If $M_n=\left(C_{i+j}\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$, it is known that $\det(M_n)=1$. After exploring the determinant of $P_n=\left(T_{i+j}\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$, I stumbled on the values
$$\det(P_n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(3k+1) (6k)! (2k)!}{(4k)! (4k+1)!}.$$
A quick check with OEIS reveals [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A051255). Hence I get prompted to ask:

> **QUESTION.** what is the combinatorial connection between $\det(P_n)$ and the "number of cyclically symmetric transpose complement plane partitions in a $(2n\times 2n \times 2n)$-box"?

**REMARK.** In regard to plane partitions, [Mills-Robbins-Rumsey](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X03962/1-s2.0-0012365X87901658/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHUCsC7yS%2BvNeAtL4GF1vk8NNU6XWU24lPRq%2FJ3NOZthAiApMmvL9kJ1XfiIDhIiXtKM03sZLEEvDKguVDBZXFwPfyq9AwjJ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMjeQiWFu6Qq7RGsBOKpEDyacJl%2B1jii%2Bu7DuUjjG3Wfp3nPrvbGgFsg86QWocTs7WuUKaJZaobazMd8nZ%2BMUo9VUj6OiUi%2FH10lTgqZwanVCyxHSH229vbotvJGwvqNK%2Fo9odCXZK6lqibuO4Jr7vg2OAL2nGom2nCZYU%2FCDdLqWY4o1MZgKnzejWlTEqR0u8DiJknxIyOzQTzOAsz3rCKxdRe9ItUgO79kEOGou3xehAXF2oNE76o2u9VV5M5xAJU8rKq1iqZ0cxZ24gh4kdNw3widZt%2BpVYCh2chLWjrOnI6dJO8XrDdUv3Mf2LGh%2FUIc19irD8cm8V7FMqy%2Bk4G3LqaavCaHqWe3EAdSt5iF%2FO3X%2Fnd0UBhB%2FJQknfyRNxijLcBH7LEcwyd8avByWTXAQRtU6bBP8BiJ2EpNnb4JaPcuRMo%2F9dTMCDX1PF5cG93pvBKuBrS0RGL7ywmJ1zCfM9TxDsEDa1UDSPbaPENBKp5gAHcuwvEfJikgMradWly2bJwZDdgJ39n3TCCbf4UrBmDYRW1EM7IyMtgPyN66Uwj4LE%2FwU67AFj1eTmDFtcuOXzAH%2B2jfXreOYhc9c7%2B%2BIk0gTuXNYCVBin5m3qlM4Du1y0V2xwUvHKdRhgcaxig0yr2FoJnvVga8XBnPv5qUgNtN2OUA1%2BuDf%2B1HOX3Gl%2BFH1NFl7ZalaQXrBZE2zcwwTzimAZfW9XYtPkqpbyeedMjckh4uNmupWZAP7HF8HeQkI4kgbonpE29%2BgmzCjC9daKzt4q0xOzo1IHKhd5q%2Bg3LxQHbbo91SqG9h05d6ifQAYtXxEfe8thQAB81cWdFeAQf8myXkWbRADmL4aJricV7OvnLjXz38YYJr6KGA426iBshw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210103T003725Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=299&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5A2CRCTY%2F20210103%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d573c24c1af3ab379a4a1ae4690cce40f814fb77a5d14edd7d47942544045adc&hash=d12236ed5458ecdd38efbafeadbe34ae6b5d0d68cfab55bf6eaa4b9e28ea5e8b&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0012365X87901658&tid=spdf-89e6ccfd-0f25-4e09-943e-f711820e55b4&sid=d8498a674477184ad4587770a21d60a169ffgxrqa&type=client) use the determinant of the matrix
$$\left(\sum_{t=0}^{2n-2}\binom{i}{t-i}\binom{j}{2j-t}\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}.$$

Comment: There's probably a Lindstrom-Gessel-Viennot interpretation. By the way, for entries of $M_n$ you mean $C_{i+j}$, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins: (1) as for proving the evaluation, yes there are a few ways of doing this including the G-V interpretations. (2) you're right, the typo is fixed.Thanks.

Comment: Your $T_n$ are just Fuss-Catalan numbers. The core interpretation is not the most common: ternary trees, or quadrangulations are more common interpretations of the $T_n$.

Comment: I mentioned cores exactly for the reason that it is uncommon, all the rest is available on OEIS.