# Fuss-Catalan: how does equality of these determinants hold?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants, enumerative-combinatorics

There are many ways that the *Catalan numbers* seemed to have been generalized, one among them is through what Graham-Knuth-Patashnik (in Concrete Mathematics) dubbed as the *Fuss-Catalan numbers*
$\frac1{bk+1}\binom{bk+1}k$.

I would like to tie these up with computing Hankel determinants, as follows.

> **QUESTION.** If $b\in\mathbb{N}$, then is this true?
> $$(b+1)^n\det\left[\sum_{k=0}^{i+j}\frac{x^{i+j-k}}{bk+1}\binom{bk+k}k\right]_{i,j=0}^n
> =\det\left[\sum_{k=0}^{i+j}x^{i+j-k}\binom{bk+k}k\right]_{i,j=0}^n.$$

**Postscript.** Actually, the question is generalized by inserting a variable $x$. The special case, $b=2$ and $x=0$ revives [my earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380253/number-of-cyclically-symmetric-tc-plane-partitions-vs-a-determinant) and in addition it offers (yet) another formulation of the number of cyclically symmetric transpose complement plane partitions in a $(2n\times 2n\times 2n)$-box via
$$\frac1{3^n}\det\left[\binom{3i+3j}{i+j}\right]_{i,j=0}^n.$$